# How can the app be launched in different screens depending on whether the user is logged or not?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want the app to remeber when the user is logged, I'm trying to use DataStore to store the email and password of the user and then when the app opens, if there is an email and a password, the user is logged. This check is to show or not show the login screen, if the user is not logged, then it navigates to the login screen, if it is logged, then it navigates to the home screen.

Currently, in the MainActivity I check if it is logged, saving it in a boolean and then passing it to the NavHost to select one startActivity (LoginScreen) or another (HomeScreen). The problem is that the code is faster than the check, so the logged doesn't have time to set to true and then it always show the login screen. How can I solve it? Maybe there is a cleaner way to do this but so far this is what I come up with. The only solution I found is checking if the user is logged in the login screen, but this causes the screen to flicker for a moment.

I'll leave some code fragments:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        setContent {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            val dataStore = StoreUserInfo(context)
            
            val userEmail = dataStore.getEmail.collectAsState(initial = "").value
            val userPass = dataStore.getPass.collectAsState(initial = "").value
            var logged = false
            
            if(userEmail!!.isNotBlank() && userPass!!.isNotBlank()) {
                logged = true
            }
            
            ...
            MyApp(logged)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    ...
    NavGraph(
        finishActivity = finishActivity,
        navController = navController,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPaddingModifier),
        userLogged = logged
    )
}

@Composable
fun NavGraph(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    finishActivity: () -> Unit = {},
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = Screen.Inicio.route,
    userLogged: Boolean,
    navigator: Navigator
) {
    val loginComplete = remember(userLogged) {
        mutableStateOf(userLogged)
    }
    
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
        navigation(
            route = Screen.Home.route,
            startDestination = BottomMenu.Home.route
        ) {
            home(...)
        }
        composable(Screen.Login.route) {
            LoginScreen(...)
        }
    }   
}

@Composable
fun NavGraphBuilder.inicio(...) {
    composable(BottomMenu.Home.route) { from ->
        LaunchedEffect(loginComplete) {
            if (!loginComplete.value) { 
                navController.navigate(Screen.Login.route)
            }
        }
        if (loginComplete.value) {
            HomeFragment(...)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using multiple activities? Are you migrating your app from the older view-based system to Compose or is your app entirely written in Compose?

Comment: I edited the code, I only have one activty all the other methods are composables

Answer (score 0):

You can't launch different Activities. What you can do in the onCreate of the first Activity is check for the user being logged in, and if he is immediately launch the Activity you really want and finish the existing Activity.  If you do it in onCreate it will never be shown.

Comment: sorry if I worded it wrong but I only have one Activity, the other methods are composables. I have the login check in the onCreate but the code runs faster, doing debugging you can see that the first check is false because the code runs faster and the dataStore hasn't yet collected the email and the password, but later it reruns this part and then it's true

Comment: Then that may be a usecase for a splash screen.  Show a splash screen while you read all your data into memory, then transition from the splash screen to one of the other screens based on login screen.  If you can't get a result by the end of onCreate, the first screen will be displayed.

Comment: Another idea may be to store login state in Shared Preferences, which would allow you to quickly access if the user is logged in, even if you can't load all his data in time.